# Installing mod_xsendfile in MAMP Pro causes Apache not to load

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro, x-sendfile, apache-modules

I am on OSX Yosemite and currently trying to install mod_xsendfile. I followed all the steps there without encountering any problems: http://patrickward.com/2013/01/07/adding-the-x-sendfile-module-to-mamp-pro/

Now, when I try to start MAMP Pro, it says that Apache could not start. If I look in the error log, there is nothing that appears except for that line:

```
[Sun Nov 30 11:17:18 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I have included the module in the MAMP httpd.conf so I can toggle the module on or off in the GUI. If I toggle off mod_xsendfile, Apache starts. If it is on, it does not start without any errors.

I checked to see if maybe it wasn't compiled for the same architecture:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Etienne:modules etienne$ file mod_headers.so 
mod_headers.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
MacBook-Pro-de-Etienne:modules etienne$ file mod_xsendfile.so 
mod_xsendfile.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

I checked for the permissions but they are the same as well:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 etienne  admin    13864 20 oct 10:23 mod_userdir.so
-rw-rw-r--  1 etienne  admin    18896 20 oct 10:23 mod_usertrack.so
-rw-rw-r--  1 etienne  admin    13404 20 oct 10:23 mod_version.so
-rw-rw-r--  1 etienne  admin    14128 20 oct 10:23 mod_vhost_alias.so
-rw-rw-r--  1 etienne  admin  2238836 20 oct 10:23 mod_wsgi.so
-rw-rw-r--  1 etienne  admin    15572 30 nov 10:58 mod_xsendfile.so
```

I really don't know what could be the problem...